# FabricJS iText grow from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

How can you make a text object on the FabricJS canvas grow/shrink from the center and expand bidirectionally when text is added or removed?

I have tried adding `centeredScaling: true` but this is only for resizing (scaling) the object, not adding/removing text.

If you check my demo you'll see that when you click the text and add more characters to the object it expands to the right only, leaving the text off center.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var cWidth = 600;
var cHeight = 200;

canvas.setWidth(cWidth);
canvas.setHeight(cHeight);


function Addtext() {
  canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Text', {
    left: (cWidth / 2) - 83,
    top: (cHeight / 2) - 25,
    fontFamily: 'arial black',
    fill: '#333',
    fontSize: 50,
    centeredScaling: true,
  }));
}
```

```css
 #c {
   border: 1px solid red;
   top: 22px;
   left: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="Addtext()">Add Text</button>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `align` and origin of x and y to `center`.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var cWidth = 600;
var cHeight = 200;

canvas.setWidth(cWidth);
canvas.setHeight(cHeight);


function Addtext() {
  canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Text', {
    left: (cWidth / 2) - 83,
    top: (cHeight / 2) - 25,
    fontFamily: 'arial black',
    fill: '#333',
    fontSize: 50,
    align: 'mid', //added
  originX: 'center', //added
  originY: 'center', //added
    centeredScaling: true,
  }));
}
```

```css
 #c {
   border: 1px solid red;
   top: 22px;
   left: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="Addtext()">Add Text</button>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: I didn't find this in the iText documentation, maybe I wasn't looking in the right place :)